# Filter a user data using contains in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have this model that records data in slug. The user has a relation with the award model. What am trying to do is list all login user's awards slug field data in the contain filter so i can use it to filter user's data.

**NOTE** : All the data in save in the SuccessfulTransactionHistory model field award is in slug format and SuccessfulTransactionHistory model has no foreign key relation to award and user

```
models.py

class Award(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='award_images')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    about_the_award = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_PUBLISHED, default='Closed')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, default='0.5',  decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True, validators = [MinValueValidator(0.1)])
    bulk_voting = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=BULK_VOTING, default='Closed')
    amount = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, blank=True,)
    results_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=RESULTS_PUBLISHED, default='private')
    starting_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ending_date = models.DateTimeField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class SuccessfulTransactionHistory(models.Model):
    nominee_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    award = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    amount = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In my view.py

```
success_list = SuccessfulTransactionHistory.objects.filter(award__contains=request.user.award.slug).order_by('-date')
```

This is my error

```
'User' object has no attribute 'award'

 ``
```

Comment: Have you simply tried printing out "request" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your User object has a lot of awards, because you use ForeignKey.
The relation is: One award has one User, but One user has one or more than one awards (award_set is the property name).
Solutions? Yes, of course,but depends on the context.

1- If the user has only one award, you can use [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/), and your logic is ok.

2- If the user can have more than one Award, may be you need 2 steps.

**Step 1**: get all award slugs:

```
award_slugs = list(request.user.award_set.values_list('slug', flat=True))
```

where `award_slugs` is a list of slugs.

**Step 2**: Get success_list:

```
success_list = SuccessfulTransactionHistory.objects.filter(award__in=award_slugs)
```